# Sequentially concatenate panel data stored in HDFStore Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set consisting of number of Pandas Panels with time along the major axis. Pandas concat method allows for a concatenation of the panels such that the minor axes share a common time index, which is exactly what I need. Missing values are conveniently replaced with NaN.

```
dat1 = np.random.randn(1, 3, 3) 
pan1 = pd.Panel(dat1, 
              items=['One'], 
              major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=3),
              minor_axis=['A', 'B', 'C'])
dat2 = np.random.randn(1, 3, 3)
pan2 = pd.Panel(dat2, 
              items=['Two'], 
              major_axis=pd.date_range('1/2/2000', periods=3),
              minor_axis=['A', 'B', 'C'])
panc = pd.concat([pan1, pan2])
```

The following slices provide exactly the type of data access that I seek to achieve.

```
panc.loc['One',:,:]
panc.loc[:,:,'A']
```

The problem is that I have a very large number of panels each with thousands of data points. I anticipate that eventually a sequentialy concatenated panel will saturate the memory available to me. I would thus like to store the panel data in an HDF5 file using Pandas HDFStore.

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5',)
store.put('panc', panc, format='table')
```

The above commands work well for a pre-concatenated panel, but I have not been able to figure out how to concatenate to an existing panel in the store.  My questions are:

Is it possible to sequentially concatenate panels within a store similar to the Pandas concat example above? (I have not been able to achive this with the HDFStore append method, possibly because I do not fully understand well enough how append works.)

Is there another, smarter approach to storing the data in the HDF5 file that provides the organization I need along a common major axis (time) while allowing access of the data as if they were stored as a panel?